# How to add a barrier with access to roll in and out trash bins in my 'public' driveway?

Tags: fence

I have a driveway that is in the back alley.  All of our neighbors have access to the back alley.  Also, all of my neighbors have basically built on their property so that they have used up their driveway.

All of our trash cans are also in the back alley.  Some neighbors roll their trash cans onto their property.

However, some of my neighbors (I don't know which), always put their trash bins in my driveway.  When we first moved here there were SIX trash cans.  Only two of them belong to me.

My question is, how do I prevent people from accessing my driveway (it's about 40' wide and 26' deep).  I would want to put up a barrier on the 40' span.

```
---------------------------------
              alley
---------------------------------
+              40'              +
+                               +
+                               +
+                               +
+           drive way           +
+                               +
--------- garage door/wall------+
```

I don't want to install a fence just yet, I just want a deterrent.  But I still need to roll my trash cans in and out of the driveway for trash collection in the alley.

**UPDATE**
I've moved the bins and also talked to the neighbors but the bins still end up on my property.  Or sometimes they will take my bins if they run out of space in their bins.

Comment: Ask who those trashbins belong to and look for a solution by interacting with those people. Technical solutions to social problems leads to issues.

Comment: If you would install a low wall to prevent people rolling their trash bins onto your property this would be a tripping hazard. If someone did trip and got injured, this would expose you to legal liability. Trying to change a long standing practice is not easy. It would require tact and in the end it might be best if you would just accept, for the time being anyway, that your property is supplying space for some neighbors to leave their trash bins for collection. Is the trash collection manual or by machine lift?

Comment: I often in cases of territorialism, one discovers the property lines specified on the deed does not contain the disputed spaces... Perhaps they are not invading you, but your slab is invading public right of way. Once I had a neighbor tenant enraged that I used a street parking space in front of his former garage converted to bedroom (as he usually did). He pointed to the still existing curb cut and called it a "driveway". .Turns out that should've been removed!  The owner did the bedroom conversion without permits, and the city ordered him to **evict the tenant** and remove it.  Whoops!

Comment: They are definitely on my property. The previous owner of the house was probably lenient about this.  ALSO, this other neighbor use to park their car in my drive way. I talked to him and he continued to do it. I had to be really firm one day with my language and he eventually stopped. Now our interactions are a little awkward.

Comment: @milesmeow then negotiate a new agreement. Don't immediately start bullying people because they don't do what you want them to do without communicating *what* you want them to do.

Comment: Noting the update, please make sure to answer Jim's quesiton about whether burly trash men muscle the bins into the back of their truck, or an automatic grabber mechanism on the side of the truck flips the bins into the top.  Also, are you new to urban living?

Comment: Not to belabor the point, but your property probably doesn't extend to the edge of the alley. Do you know the distance from the center of the alley that the right-of-way extends? Most folks would be shocked to learn how much of "their" yard they don't actually own.

Comment: I'm certain that the trash cans are on my property based on all of my neighbors and the block wall fences that they've built around their property lines. The trash cans are not bordering the alley or in an area that may be in dispute. They are placed right by my garage.

Comment: Well, that's just weird.

Comment: @ratchetfreak : I don't see how I'm displaying bullying behavior by 'fencing' my property. Please help me understand.

Comment: @isherwood Yes, that's what I think so I'm trying to figure out an appropriate solution. The low barrier doesn't have to be that low so it's not a tripping hazard. It could waist or shoulder level.

Comment: @milesmeow "bullying" may have been a bit too strong of a term. But the point still stands

Comment: Gotta love neighbors. We have a setup very similar to your own except each house had their own location on their own property for their trash. Our driveway is like this and used to be open. We would come home some times and have random cars (friends of neighbors) parked in our driveway or mid-process of turning around in it. We eventually put up a full yard fence for our dogs and an entry gate. Solved the issue. I know it's not what you want, so I'm not including this as an answer. By the way, as @ratchetfreak mentioned - the neighbors did not like our technical solution either.

Answer (score 2):

A few ideas, not knowing what the area really looks like.

1. Over time seek to identify the various mystery bins and mark them with names or house numbers in permanent ink. When they appear on your property you can either bring it up with your neighbor or ask the local police for help. This may also work through peer pressure. If your neighbors see their names sitting on your property they may be less likely to violate your space. (I find that turning on my hazard flashers is the best way to deal with tailgaters--the unwanted attention very often mitigates the poor behavior.)
2. Fabricate a temporary gate, such as suspended cables with wire mesh between, that you can install the day before trash day each week and roll up when not needed. Put it up, take it down. Like when training a puppy, your neighbors will become conditioned to do something else.

Comment: Good idea. :) I've labelled my bins already so that I know and communicate which ones are mine.

Comment: I think you've reached the point where it would be appropriate to label theirs. I completely understand your frustration.

Comment: I don't know which neighbor it belongs to. I can put up the cable and roll the bins into the alley where others have place their bins.

Comment: It would involve sitting out with a beverage after pickup to see who comes by. Heck, even that might do the trick. "Hey, [neighbor name], I see you've taken it upon yourself to borrow my property again. How nice!"

Comment: Or a security camera to monitor activity by my driveway

Answer (score 2):

I would start by considering your needs, not the aesthetics.  If the bins don't get in the way of your family's cars, then fuggedabadit.  If they are an impediment, then....

If you are Ok with a drastic solution, 
first be committed to keeping your own bins inside your garage until trash day.  Next, any evening you come home to find others' bins on your driveway,  roll those into your garage for subsequent destruction and disposal.

Answer (score 2):

### The neighbors aren't doing it. The trash man is.

The garbage truck has an automatic grabber specifically designed to work with the types of cans you have been issued by the city.  They have rectangular tops but roundish middles, and wheels and a lid hinge on the same side.   All by design.  The trash pickup process is as follows.

- hop out of truck.
- drag all nearby cans to the (typically) right side of the truck in a neat row.
- inch the truck forward until it is abeam of the first can.
- push button.
- Grabber lifts can to top of truck, inverts, dumps, sets back down.
- inch forward to next can and repeat as above.
- **Drive away**.

Citizens are expected to, at this point, sort out their own trash cans like grownups.  *In fact, the duty to do so may even be in your garbage contract.*

It may also be the case that a kindly neighbor is routinely doing the gracious act of positioning the cans *for* the garbage man so he can move through his day that much quicker.

The latter particularly, and this process in general, is something you **do not want to mess with**.  Territorialism is all fun and games until you cheese off a dragon, Norse god, British Empire, highly advanced extraterrestrial, or garbage man.

One time I parked my car (street parking) in a way the garbage man had trouble getting to the cans.  I found my car entirely boxed in by garbage cans.   Every week the next month, I put every can in the area in a nice straight line on the right side of the street for him to grab.   *Message received.*

This sort of thing is just part of the daily  give and take of high density living, or should I say "medium" since parking a car is possible.

Comment: :). Our trash service is not that nice. I have to roll the trash cans from the garage area to the alley form pickup to happen. Then when it's done in have to roll it back.

Comment: I think you misunderstood Harper's answer. I think (s)he's onto something here.

Comment: i.e. there is no step  "drag the cans back where he found them". That step does not happen.